# Animating item removal from LongListSelector

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, triggers, windows-phone

So I have a View Model bound to a collection of custom objects with some properties (Name, Size etc) which implements NotifyPropertyChanged so the LongListSelector updates accordingly.

Now I want to add some animations to the LongListSelector which will fade in an item when it's added and fade out an item when it's removed. I've managed to get the add animation to work when Grid.Loaded fires so I thought I could also call the reverse animation (fade out) on Grid.Unload but I'm having no success.

I've had look at:
Grid.Unload (never fires for some reason), Grid.LayoutUpdated (fires too many times),
Triggers PropertyChangedTrigger (I thought if I bound this to a property like "Remove", then I could animate it when that property is set to true, but stuck on how to implement this. However, this seems to be my best option at this stage), Styles EventTrigger (but no event was what I was looking for. Maybe I could create a new event for LongListSelector, but that would require more time to create either a control which inherits from it).

So I'm wondering what other options are available to me? Or if anyone has been in similar situations that could share some knowledge!

EDIT - This is for a Windows Phone application, so some classes aren't available to me.
EDIT 2 - Just for clarification, I can make Storyboards for the grid and reduce the opacity but the way my code is, a method handles the removal of items which has no way of locating the grid to begin that storyboard. I was also stuck on this earlier but decided to change my implementation for another issue. As it stands, my LongListSelector's ItemTemplate is bound to a PhoneApplicationResource (equivalent to a Resource) DataTemplate and I've had no luck locating the grid inside this template.
EDIT 3 - Just had a go at DataTriggers and seems to be going well:

```
           <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ic:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDeleted}" Value="true">
                    <eim:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource fade}"/>
                </ic:DataTrigger>
            </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
```

IsDeleted is working because I tested it in another binding to see its value, however when I run the above code I get a debug.break() error. It only appears when I run the above code. Here is my storyboard for reference:

```
                <Storyboard x:Name="fade">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="95" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" SpeedRatio="1" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1.0" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" SpeedRatio="1" />
                </Storyboard>
```

Note: Both are located within a DataTemplate in a grid in PhoneApplicationPage.Resources and only the storyboard is located in Grid.Resources like so:

```
<PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
     <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
               //DataTrigger here

               <Grid.Resources>
                  // Storyboard here
               </Grid.Resources>
          </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
</PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried FluidMoveBehavior on your ItemsPanelTemplate? That might give you a bit more flexibility.